# python about multiple %s in a string

Tags: python, string

```
str = 'I love %s and %s, he loves %s and %s.'
```

I want to use this format to display

I love apple and pitch, he loves apple and pitch.

Only add two variable please, but need a way to use it twice in one sentence.

Comment: And please don't **ever** call a variable `str`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
>>> s = 'I love %(x)s and %(y)s, he loves %(x)s and %(y)s.'
>>> s % {"x" : "apples", "y" : "oranges"}
'I love apples and oranges, he loves apples and oranges.'
```

Or use the newer [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function, which was introduced in 2.6:

```
>>> s = 'I love {0} and {1}, she loves {0} and {1}'
>>> s.format("apples", "oranges")
'I love apples and oranges, she loves apples and oranges'
```

Note: Calling a variable `str` would mask the built-in function [`str([object])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: Is there any reason why one should use `format` rather than a dictionary? Or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: I believe the `.format` [spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) just covers more cases. A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/89391. My personal preference is to use `%` for brevity and performance and `.format`, if readability is improved.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> str = 'I love %(1)s and %(2)s, he loves %(1)s and %(2)s.' % {"1" : "apple", "2" : "pitch"}
>>> str
'I love apple and pitch, he loves apple and pitch.'
```

Of course you can use other names besides '1' and '2'. :)